# Building a vector starting with 1 and followed by zeros using vector concatenation and replication

Tags: verilog

I have the following Verilog code that is throwing an error that I can't quite manage to figure out:

```
module error #(parameter WIDTH = 8);
  reg [WIDTH - 1:0] v;
  
  initial begin
    v <= {1'b1, {WIDTH - 1}{1'b0}};
  end
  
endmodule
```

I basically want `v` to be a vector that starts with a `1` and is followed by a bunch of `0`. For example, if the parameter `WIDTH` is `8`, I want to obtain the vector `10000000`.

The code above is giving me an error that says 'expecting a right brace' and 'expecting a semicolon'. I think I just don't quite understand the syntax for vector replication and/or concatenation. I tried a bunch of combinations for the syntax, like using `()` instead of `{}`, adding extra `{}` to the `1`, using the `b` syntax or not using it, without any success.

The `parameter`, as well as the usage of the concatenation syntax is necessary for my actual design, the code above being just a small module to showcase the issue, so ideally I would like to find out why this error occurs and what should I change in my syntax to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The braces are not placed properly.

Change:

```
v <= {1'b1, {WIDTH - 1}{1'b0}};
```

to:

```
v <= {1'b1, {(WIDTH - 1){1'b0}}};
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.12.1 *Replication operator*

The parentheses are not required, but I think they make the code easier to understand.